# Lazify State Machine

Tags: haskell

I am beginner to Haskell and I am trying to write a Lexer State Machine that is Lazy.

I have this code that definitive is no lazy code. Thus what kind of library or pattern should I use to lazy-fy this code?

```hs
module Main where

import           Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import           Data.Sequence (Seq (..))
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

data Suppe = A | B Integer

data StateBase = StateBase String (Seq Suppe)

newtype StateFn = StateFn (StateBase -> (Maybe StateFn, StateBase))

type StateMachine = (Maybe StateFn, StateBase)

next :: StateMachine -> StateMachine
next (Just (StateFn f), x) = f x
next (Nothing, x) = (Nothing, x)

run :: String -> Seq Lexeme
run input = evalState go (Just startStateFn, startState) 
  where
    startState = StateBase input Seq.empty
    startStateFn = FnA

    go :: State StateMachine (Seq Lexeme)
    go = get >>= \stateMachine -> let newStateMachine = next stateMachine
      in
      case fst newStateMachine of
        (Just _) -> put newStateMachine >> go
        Nothing -> return $ getSeq $ snd newStateMachine
    getSeq :: StateBase -> Seq Suppe
    getSeq (StateBase _ seq) = seq

fnA :: StateFn
fnA = undefined

fnB :: StateFn
fnB = undefined

main = undefined
```

I am using `containers ^>= 0.6.0.1, mtl ^>= 2.2`

Comment: Do you have a lazy parser? That would be very unusual, and if you don't, then it seems like lazifying your lexer won't matter much. What do your `fnA` and `fnB` do with the `Seq Suppe`? Is it always consing onto the front (or back)?

Comment: @DanielWagner I still have no parser, but it will be as lazy as possible. they are example functions for the Lexer State Fucntions, but is convention that all of them push to the back, ergo add at the back. (Considering the reference is a Haskell native list)

Comment: In my experience laziness for things like lexers and parsers isn't always that nice, because it means functions for lexing/parsing a stream of text/tokens are necessarily partial. To be lazy, they need to generate the outermost parts of their output examining only a prefix of their input. But that means an error deeper into the input can't be flagged with a "nice" error ADT, you just have to error out. That means anything *consuming* the result has trouble behaving nicely in the presence of errors too; they have to be ready for anything to be an error.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like you have way too much machinery lying around, and it's just cluttering things up and making it too hard to see where laziness is being lost. Have you tried just using direct-style programming? Something like this:

```
import Data.Char

data Lexeme = A | B Integer

stateAOrB :: String -> [Lexeme]
stateAOrB ('A':rest) = stateA rest
stateAOrB ('B':rest) = stateB 0 rest
stateAOrB (_:rest) = error "lex error" -- or, could return [Maybe Lexeme] or [Either PositionInformation Lexeme] or whatever
stateAOrB [] = []

stateA :: String -> [Lexeme]
stateA cs = A : stateAOrB cs

stateB :: Integer -> String -> [Lexeme]
stateB n (c:cs) | isDigit c = stateB (10*n + toInteger (digitToInt c)) cs
stateB n other = B n : stateAOrB other
```

I would guess this is shorter (or only negligibly longer) than implementations of `fnA` and `fnB` in your setting, while being clear and quite visibly lazy.

Comment: My current setting has character counting to help too error messages when I go to implement it, and also did no make integer recognition letting that work for the parse and also to help with error management  when comes the time to implement error messages, so there is some more code but there is also some more futures.